Eas build failed in Bundle Javascript
i encourter the same error since 2 days when i make "eas build --platform ios --profile production" and i don't know how to handle it. I've just updated to expo 52 and since then I've been getting this error.
Did Someone have an idea ?
The error occur in step Bundle Javacript.

$ /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/.bin/expo export:embed --eager --platform ios --dev false

Starting Metro Bundler

iOS Bundled 35398ms node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js (2863 modules)

Exporting server

λ Bundled 5330ms node_modules/expo-router/build/static/getServerManifest.js (571 modules)

Metro error: No routes found

Error: No routes found

    at apply (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-router/build/static/getServerManifest.js:27:15)

    at getBuildTimeServerManifestAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/getStaticRenderFunctions.ts:112:25)

    at MetroBundlerDevServer.getServerManifestAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:260:29)

    at exportApiRoutesStandaloneAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/exportStaticAsync.ts:404:30)

    at exportStandaloneServerAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportServer.ts:62:3)

    at exportEmbedBundleAndAssetsAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportEmbedAsync.ts:220:7)

    at exportEmbedInternalAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportEmbedAsync.ts:125:37)

    at exportEmbedAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportEmbedAsync.ts:105:3)

No routes found

Error: No routes found

Error: No routes found

    at apply (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-router/build/static/getServerManifest.js:27:15)

    at getBuildTimeServerManifestAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/getStaticRenderFunctions.ts:112:25)

    at MetroBundlerDevServer.getServerManifestAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:260:29)

    at exportApiRoutesStandaloneAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/exportStaticAsync.ts:404:30)

    at exportStandaloneServerAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportServer.ts:62:3)

    at exportEmbedBundleAndAssetsAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportEmbedAsync.ts:220:7)

    at exportEmbedInternalAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportEmbedAsync.ts:125:37)

    at exportEmbedAsync (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportEmbedAsync.ts:105:3)

error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

yarn expo export:embed --eager --platform ios --dev false exited with non-zero code: 1


Thanks in advance

Having a similar issue. Mine looks like this:
Exporting server λ Bundling failed 12316ms node_modules/expo-router/build/static/getServerManifest.js (2730 modules) Error: Unable to resolve module ../../Utilities/Platform from /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInputState.js: 
Any news?

I have no issue with this. I downgraded expo version to 51 and it work.
